# How do I show a suffix to user input in Python?

Tags: python

I want a percentage sign to display after the users enters their number. Thanks

```
percent_tip = float(input(" Please Enter the percent of the tip:")("%"))
```

For example, before the user types anything they should see:

```
Please Enter the percent of the tip:
```

Once they begin typing the number `20` they should see:

```
Please Enter the percent of the tip: 20
```

After they hit `<Enter>` they should see:

```
Please Enter the percent of the tip: 20%
```

Comment: After the number was entered? Just behind the number as it is being entered?

Comment: Yes after the number is entered. For example, if the number is 20 then I want 20% to display.

Comment: After the final number has been entered? Or also while typing?

Comment: After the final number is entered

Comment: But directly after the user-input number?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this if this is what you are asking for:

```
import sys
import time

percent_tip = ""

while percent_tip in "123456789": # This part checks with the "if" statement, if its not a integer then it returns
    percent_tip = input("Please Enter the % of the tip: ")
    if percent_tip in "123456789":
        print(str(percent_tip) + " %") # Prints the number and the percentage symbol
        sys.exit() #stops the shell

    else:
        time.sleep(.100) #Shell waits then goes back in the while loop (unless its controlled by the "while" and "if")
```

Please do not try to harden yourself with a code that you don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows, you will have the [`msvcrt`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/msvcrt.html) module available. It provides, among others, the `getwche()` function, giving you the key pressed. This allows you to act on individual characters, and then print the % at the end (if you play around a bit more, you can probably also get it to appear while typing).

Example:

```
def get_chars(): 
     chars = []              
     new = msvcrt.getwche()     
     while new != '\r':  # returns \r on <RETURN> press
             # you probably want to do some input validation here
             chars.append(new)
             new = msvcrt.getwche()  # get the next one
     print(end='%', flush=True)
     return ''.join(chars)  # this returns a str, you might want to directly get an int
```

Also, you will probably want to add input validation inside to make sure the input is only numbers.