# Suffix after user input

Tags: python

I want accept the input from the user but i want to mention the standard unit of input in the input statement and print it but i am getting an error

```
temp_fah = float(input("Enter temperature in fahrenhite :  " + "℉"))
Enter temperature in fahrenhite :  ℉
```

The cursor points after ℉ symbol to enter data

Comment: [non accepted duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55078535/1324033) - the tl;dr is its not worth the effort

Comment: Sounds like a problem best solved with a GUI.

Comment: one thing you can do that, 
> at first, you should print  `"Enter temperature in fahrenhite :  "`
> once there is an input comes, you need to remove that line and reprint with input value like  `"Enter temperature in fahrenhite :  20℉ "`

Comment: One of the many benefits of the Celsius scale is that it is easier to spell than Fahrenheit.

Answer (score 0):

The following might not work in some IDE's.

Append `backspaces` to the input string to position the cursor in front of `°F`.

```py
prompt = 'enter temp: __ °F' + chr(0x08)*5  # 5x BACKSPACE
temp = input(prompt)
```

Input will look like this:

```
enter temp: __ °F
            ^cursor
```